# In postgresql, when i setup a remote connection does the 'slave' side caches information?

Tags: postgresql, synchronization, replication

As an example, if computer A has the original database and computer B is targeted and setted to receive that database, will B store data (cache) on the local postgresql server or it will continuosly fetch data from the source? The purpose of this question is to know if I configure such connection I'll lose data transfer velocity and will be permanently dependented from internet connection. Any suggestion in estabilishing a good framework for a erp / point of sale remote relation is very welcome also. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends entirely on the client. None of the client libraries I'm aware of for PostgreSQL do any query result caching - certainly not `libpq`, `psqlODBC`, `pgJDBC`, the Ruby `Pg` gem, Perl's `DBD::Pg`, or Python's `psycopg2`.

Some higher level abstractions and ORM systems will do caching - Ruby ActiveRecord, Hibernate/EclipseLink and other JPA implementations, etc. This caching is rarely able to satisfy queries offline, it's usually to reduce re-fetches of unchanged object *data* after confirming that object ids are in the result set.

If you want an offline database what you will need is *asynchronous multi-master replication* or an application-layer syncing and conflict resolution algorithm. I strongly recommend the latter; async multi-master replication sounds great but in practice it's absolutely horrible, especially with unpredictable periods of disconnection. Your app needs to keep a log of changes and communicate with a central server to exchange sets of changes. You must plan extremely carefully to handle conflicts; I don't recommend trying to DIY this for financial applications.

There's a lot of literature on this topic and many articles have been written. Don't reinvent the wheel, start reading what's out there. You'll find quite a bit of info about the use of sync to and from local SQLite databases in mobile apps, for example.

Comment: Wow, you've nailed it @Craig.. really, thanks for your help! ps. on a sidenote, the bigger the independent **generation** of data from the non-source database the bigger the chances of getting conflict issues right? Example, if A and B generate sales and product data that goes into the sales / products tables it has more chances of conflicts that if I setted to only replicate the products tables? (can you replicate only selected tables at all?)

Comment: @matt_zarro In general that'd be true, but it depends on the nature of your app. If your disconnected DBs only generate new records and don't update existing records then all you have to do is pick a suitable globally unique offline identifier allocation scheme and you're done. You can use GUIDs or use `(nodeid,sequenceid)` primary key tuples, either works fine.

Comment: @matt_zarro As for what you can/can't replicate and how, that depends on what replication you're using. Pg's built-in replication is unidirectional single-master, you cannot use it for this. You need to look at Londiste, Bucardo, Slony-I, etc if you want to do this in the database, but *that is really the wrong approach*. **Sync your change sets at the application level**, disconnected async replication at the DB level is really painful because by the time the app discovers a conflict it doesn't usually have the context for it anymore. As I said, read the literature and articles out there.

Comment: That's exactly what i needed to know, you're a very good explainer. For future users of SO  who struggle with this topic like me what are good readings, at least the ones that helped you grasping essential concepts? I'm a very diligent person and don't like things 'loose', I want this to be in a high standard.

Comment: @matt_zarro I don't have any specific references to hand and this isn't a problem I've explored in depth. Feel free to comment or post a 2nd answer with a write-up and good references you feel were helpful when you find them.